# Why can't I use the component directly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to use my component within `SwiperSlide`: using this directly inside it does work:

```
<Swiper>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
          </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

but if do something like:

```
const Foo = () =>
  <SwiperSlide>
    <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
  </SwiperSlide>
;

<Swiper>
         <Foo />
</Swiper>
```

it doesn't work. later on I found this works:

```
<Swiper>
         {Foo()}
</Swiper>
```

but i'd to fix and use `<Foo />` properly, if possible.

full code:

```
    import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
    // Import Swiper React components
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
    
    // Import Swiper styles
    import "swiper/css";
    import "swiper/css/pagination";
    import "swiper/css/navigation";
    import "swiper/css/navigation";
    import "swiper/css/effect-fade";
    
    import "./styles.css";
    
    // import required modules
    import { EffectFade, Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper";
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <>
          <Swiper
            effect={"fade"}
            loop={true}
            navigation={true}
            spaceBetween={30}
            centeredSlides={true}
            autoplay={{
              delay: 5000,
              disableOnInteraction: false,
              pauseOnMouseEnter: true
            }}
            pagination={{
              clickable: true
            }}
            modules={[EffectFade, Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation]}
            className="mySwiper"
          >
            <SwiperSlide>
              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <Foo />
          </Swiper>
        </>
      );
    }

const Foo = () => (
  <SwiperSlide>
    <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
  </SwiperSlide>
);
```

live example [`here`](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-autoplay-react-forked-idh118?file=/src/App.jsx)

what am I missing? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Foo is not a proper jsx component.
and setting the display name of the custom component to SwiperSlider.
Rewrite as below.

Based on the solution found at: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4413

```
 const Foo = () => {
    return (
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  };
  Foo.displayName = "SwiperSlide";
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        effect={"fade"}
        loop={true}
        navigation={true}
        spaceBetween={30}
        centeredSlides={true}
        BannerSliderSlide={"Foo"}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 5000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
          pauseOnMouseEnter: true
        }}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true
        }}
        modules={[EffectFade, Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <Foo />
      </Swiper>
    </>
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-autoplay-react-forked-xd8xgd?file=/src/App.jsx:467-1177

Comment: doesn't work with swiper: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-autoplay-react-forked-idh118?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: @Jack I have updated the answer so that it will work with Swiper.

Comment: works like a charm. didn't know about this property.

Answer (score 1):

Probably swiper needs SwiperSlide to be a child of Swiper. Your code is injecting a middle element `<Foo />` beetween those two in the VDOM. I'm not sure how to do that abstraction, but probable you will need to add the SwiperSlide component on every item and do the abstraction with its childs

Comment: this would be better off as comment... but yeah I think it's really the case, swiper needs it to be a child but i don't know how to silve it either.